# Can not filter list on reused terms

Tags: managed-metadata

I changed a managed metadata column in a library to use a different set, but the new term set contains the same terms (or a subset - *reused* in the term management).

I've noticed that filtering on the column does not work after the change. I guess this is because the copied terms have different internal ID even though they refer to the same term.

Is this something that will eventually work after the taxonomy update scheduled job has run, or do I need to set the managed metadata values again on all the items in the library?

to reproduce, e.g.

> "MyDocumentLibrary" has a column "MetadataCol" which is of managed
>   metadata type, using termset "MySetA", containing term "Term1"
>
> I add a document, and tag it with "Term01"
>
> I reuse "Term1" in another set "MySetB"
>
> I switch the column "MetadataCol" to use "MySetB" instead of "MySetA"
>
> Result: When filtering on "Term1", I get no results.
>
> When inspecting Term1, I find that it is present in both term sets (i.e  is a single identical term)

Comment: _"filtering on the column"_ - You mean by `ContentQueryWebPart`?

Comment: Just standard filtering ny using column headings in the document library views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the library items with Sharepoint Manager, I discovered that the field values are different. The term and GUID are identical (in both the visible and the the *TaxHTfield0 hidden field) but the prefixed numbers in the *visible* field are different.

Which probably makes sense, as they AFAIK are lookup values to the taxonomy hidden list, and the reused term and the original will have different entries there.

I was hoping there would be some timer job to clean up behind the scenes after this kind of reconfiguration, but I guess I need to do some scripted changes instead.

Answer (score 0):

How did you copy the terms? Did you use the Reuse Terms or Copy Terms option? These keeps the ID the same across the multiple sets, which should allow you to not have to update anything.

Comment: Reused, across term sets. The point was to be able to reuse a relevant subset of the terms.

Comment: But you're seeing unique IDs in the new terms?

Comment: I seems so, I do not get any records when attempting to filter. I am assuming that the list items have the "old" IDs and the filter/column have the "new" (reused, terms, which I regret I do not specify at once)

Comment: Try the reuse again on one term, see if the unique ID changes. I just tested and the ID remained the same for both.

Comment: I tested it again, and it doesn't work! I had a list column configured to use a term set. I copied (reused) the terms to a 2nd term set. If I reconfigure the list to use the other term set, filtering on terms (present in both sets, and on list items) does not work.